# Map Placement Editor on PHP Website

Tags: java, php, javascript, embed

I need to add an element to my website that will allow me to edit a map. (Not HTML5)
Here is an example:
[image: CISCO Wireless Editor]

Basically it needs to be embedded in the page. It needs to show a map uploaded by the user for their location. Then they will select an item to add to the map, such as a computer or printer. After selecting an item they will either drag or click on the map to place the item.
Upon clicking save this will send this data to another page to enter all the data into a MySQL table.

The operation and concept are fairly simple. The only thing that throws me for a loop is how to actually code it for the web. I would prefer not to use Java and can not use Flash. Could this be done with Java-script?

Does anyone know of any places with tutorials about this or have advice on how to conquer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try with jquery draggable event http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to.

In the example "snap-to" linked above you can do what you are asking for.